# Retrieve output of top command using Net::SSH2

Tags: perl, ssh

I am trying to retrieve the output of top command using Net::SSH2 Perl module, But I am getting null output each time.

**Code**

```
use Net::SSH2;
use strict;

my $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();

$ssh->connect('xx.xx.xx.xx');

$ssh->auth(username => 'xxxxxx', password => 'xxxxx');

my  $channel = $ssh->channel() or do { print" [LOG ERROR]: Failed to create channel. Exiting ...\n"};

$channel->blocking(0);

$channel->shell() ;

sleep(5);

my $cmd='top -n 1';

print $channel "$cmd\n";        

sleep(5);      

while(<$channel>)
  {
     print $_;
  }


$channel->close(); 

$ssh->disconnect();
```

Can somebody please help.

Comment: Use `exec` instead of `shell`. Do not disable `blocking` mode.

Comment: @Salva : I found a way to resolve this issue. Instead of 'top -n 1', we can use 'top -b -n 1'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of 'top -n 1' or 'top', Use 'top -b -n 1'